# Dotted lines in powerbi report server

Tags: css, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I recently upgraded to powerBI report server from May 2019 to May 2020 and I noticed that when you clicked on any part of the report it will show a boarder with black dotted lines.

Can some assist me and look at the CSS file to understand what could be wrong. I tried changing the outline in the **.NormalButton:focus** section to NONE and it didnt help.

Please advise!

Thanks

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```